# javascript function only works for first input box in example

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm echoing rows of $data inside input boxes. The javascript function below copies the input value to the clipboard upon clicking the input box. The problem is the function only works for the first input box and not subsequent echoed ones. I think I need to assign a unique id to each input box and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
// for each row it is echoing the following:

echo '<input id="copy-text" type="text" value="'.$data.'" size="50">';

<script>
document.getElementById("copy-text").onclick = function() {
  this.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Er. You can't have duplicated element IDs on the same page. (Well, you can, but it won't really work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID should always be unique. When you have multiple IDs with same value javascript looks for the first match with that id and skips the rest.

If you are looping through each row, use an index like this

```
echo '<input id="copy-text_'.$i'" type="text" value="'.$data.'" size="50" onclick="copy($i)">';

<script>
     function copy(index) {
          var elem = document.getElementById("copy-text_" + index);
          elem.select();
          document.execCommand('copy');
     }
</script>
```

Comment: This is better written as `onclick="copy(this)"` and `function copy(elem) { elem.select(); ... }`. No need for IDs or ID lookup.

Comment: I'd prefer the even listener approach over `onclick` at all, but it may not matter (and may be worse).

Comment: I agree with you guys. But I just wanted correct his mistake instead of changing code a lot. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements a class:

```
echo '<input class="copy-text" type="text" value="'.$data.'" size="50">';
```

And have a single script tag that finds all those elements and binds the event handler to them:

```
function handler() {
  this.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.copy-text'))
  .forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener(handler);
  });
```